# Build summary disappeared - number of errors and warnings

Tags: .net, msbuild

seen similar questions with no answers. Trying my luck in case there are any late news.
In VS2005, vcbuild was reporting the number of warnings and errors for each project, such as:

```
MyProj - 1 error(s), 23 warning(s)
```

In VS2012 this is not reported by default.
I need the summary for assembling an automated report from the full solution build. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the logger explicitly with MSBuild using the `/logger` switch. Take a look at [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/32cd7327-fd62-4286-b519-82a2a0b98f78/) and related for several examples.

You can also write your own logger following [this guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171470.aspx) which seems to explain the flags you have to turn on.

Comment: Is that the only way, to write a logger? Doesn't MSBuild have an option to display the summary?
If not, I'm sure that many have already written such a logger to match the VS2005/8 output. Can someone be so kind as to post the logger?
Thanks!

Comment: Tried using /fileLogger /fileloggerparameters:Summary;V=minimal
but still, there is no summary at the end of each project in the log file, only at the end of the solution...